# How to format a for loop Javascript program to 2 decimal places?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, decimalformat

I tried the DecimalFormat and the parseFloat, both won't work.

```
    var NumOfOrganisms = 2;
    var DailyIncrease = .30;
    var NumOfDays;

    console.log("Day" + '\t' + "Approximate Population");
    console.log('1' + '\t' + NumOfOrganisms);

    for(NumOfDays = 2; NumOfDays <= 10; NumOfDays++) {
      NumOfOrganisms = NumOfOrganisms + (NumOfOrganisms * DailyIncrease);
      console.log(NumOfDays + '\t' + NumOfOrganisms);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the function **toFixed()** in order to accomplish this, inside, as an argument you specify the amount of places you want for the decimal number.

Here you go:

```
  var NumOfOrganisms = 2;
  var DailyIncrease = .30;
  var NumOfDays;

  console.log("Day" + '\t' + "Approximate Population");
  console.log('1' + '\t' + NumOfOrganisms);

  for (NumOfDays = 2; NumOfDays <= 10; NumOfDays++) {
      NumOfOrganisms = NumOfOrganisms + (NumOfOrganisms * DailyIncrease);
      console.log(NumOfDays + '\t' + NumOfOrganisms.toFixed(2));
  }
```